# Greek mathematics' application in the early economic theories

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought, economic-history

I am writing about the development of mathematics in the Ancient Greece as an assigment and I have to include its relation with economics. However, I lack of sources for this topic and I only found Joseph Schumpeter: History of Economic Analysis's one early chapter. Can someone recommend me any article or book in this topic?

Comment: Are you asking about the relationship between ancient Greek mathematics and ancient Greek economics? Or  ancient Greek mathematics and and the work of early economists, like say those of the classical school (like Adam Smith, David Ricardo, and John Stuart Mill)?

Comment: Both, if possible. However, as far as I know, ancinet economists didn't use maths but if there is some work inspired by maths or used I am interested in it.

Comment: Found this one [here](https://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/03068291111143910?utm_campaign=RePEc&WT.mc_id=RePEc&), maybe it will help you.